# How to solve BoxConstraints forces an infinite width exception in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-layout, flutter-animation

Hello i was just trying to include a switch button on the right side of a list item. While doing so i ended up with this BoxConstraints forces an infinite width error. As im a complete beginner to flutter Can someone please let me know what does it means? and what changes i have to do in my code to get rid of this error?

```
import 'package:attendee/constants.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:attendee/models/userdeails.dart';

class userdetailsTile extends StatelessWidget {
  final userdetails userdetail;
  userdetailsTile({this.userdetail});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Card(
            //margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 6.0, 20.0, 0.0),
            child: GestureDetector(
              child: ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  radius: 25.0,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen,
                ),
                title: Text(userdetail.fullname),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Switch(
            value: present,
            onChanged: (value) {
              //setState(() {
              present = value;
              print(present);
              //});
            },
            activeTrackColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
            activeColor: Colors.green,
          ),
          //),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check the following solutions.

- Solution 1

  ```
   return Material(child: Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
      child: ListTile(
              leading: CircleAvatar(
                radius: 25.0,
                backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen,
              ),
              title: Text(userdetail.fullname),
              trailing: Switch(
                value: present,
                onChanged: (value) {
                  //setState(() {
                  present = value;
                  print(present);
                  //});
                },
                activeTrackColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
                activeColor: Colors.green,
              ),
            ),
      ),
    );
  ```
- Solution 2

  ```
   return Material(child: 
     Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 8.0),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: <Widget>[
          Expanded(
            child: Card(
              //margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20.0, 6.0, 20.0, 0.0),
              child: Row(
                children: [
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 25.0,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.lightGreen,
                  ), Text(userdetail.fullname)
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Switch(
            value: present,
            onChanged: (value) {
              //setState(() {
              present = value;
              print(present);
              //});
            },
            activeTrackColor: Colors.lightGreenAccent,
            activeColor: Colors.green,
          ),
          //),
        ],
      ),
     ),
    );
  ```

Comment: great it worked @Mardel. Can you please let me know what caused this problem.

Comment: I've added Material Widget for Switch Widget and set the width limit using Expanded.